# powershell Send-MailMessage on some computers won't send to multiple recipients

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script for sending emails that is used by many computers (all Windows 7) on our network. This is the Send-MailMessage function that I start with (https://powershell.org/forums/topic/specifying-replyto-in-send-mailmessage/) and this is the modified version (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B54UPMspJosWckJXZ1M0SHVyVk0). For the most part I removed the Inline Attachments and asked for a little more info when it failed.

There are a couple computers that it doesn't work on. I've satisfied myself that the computer is the problem because I can take the exact script and run it from another computer.

I've checked the Firewall and it's not on. I've compared the Microsoft.NET folders and there are minor differences but I don't know what is consequential and what is not.

Another complication is that these problem computers *can* work when the TO list is one/few users instead of the 20 or 30 that is regular.

Can a .NET installation be defective? I've tried a .NET repair from Microsoft but it didn't fix this problem. Any help you can offer is appreciated!

Comment: How does it fail on the workstations that it fails on? You should edit your question to specify errors, and if you've made changes to the PowerShell.org script, it probably wouldn't be a bad idea to post your modified script as part of the question as well.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I put the update in the post. The error message is quite long too. Initially it says "Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s)." Later on it mentions "party did not properly respond after a period of time". Here it is in its entirety - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B54UPMspJosWZ2dQRHBsak9oSXM

Comment: This indicates a failure of connectivity - either `Send-MailMessage` is not able to connect to the mail server, or the mail server is having problems and not responding. Since it only fails on some computers, I would look to the network adapter settings, and also any router/switch/firewall configuration issues.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin  I'll check into what that means :) and get some help checking out these possibilities. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I wanted to post that this problem has finally been resolved. Apparently it was some kind of network issue. The IT folks did a cut-over on our network traffic routing from one system to another and that resolved the problem. Wish I could be more explicit but that's as well as I understand what happened. Just glad it's working!

Comment: Just for completeness, you might want to post that last comment as the answer to the question, accept it, and close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to post that this problem has finally been resolved. Apparently it was some kind of network issue. The IT folks did a cut-over on our network traffic routing from one system to another and that resolved the problem. Wish I could be more explicit but that's as well as I understand what happened. Just glad it's working!